# How can I use use GRASS that was installed from an image in Python3 on MacOS?

Tags: python, grass-gis, mac

I am running MacOS 10.15 and want to run GRASS 7.9 on my machine from a Python program. So I downloaded GRASS as an image [here](http://grassmac.wikidot.com/downloads).

Now I want to import the GRASS functionality into a Python program.

I have tried going into the resources of the app in my applications folder and add the Python GRASSs folder to my path. I have installed grass-session and tried to set the GRASSBIN variable to the application path. But so far I have had no success.

I have installed grass-session version 0.5 with pip, set the GRASSBIN environment variable to `/Applications/GRASS-7.9.app/Contents/MacOS/Grass` and ran `import grass_session`, but I am getting the following error:

`RuntimeError: GRASS GIS start script: /Applications/GRASS-7.9.app/Contents/MacOS/Grass --config path, return as GISBASE a directory (tab 1 of window id 16042) that do not exist.`

and GRASS opens itself!

Does someone know how to use GRASS in Python?

Comment: There has been a new release of `grass-session` yesterday, be sure to use version 0.5 (https://github.com/zarch/grass-session/releases/tag/v0.5) or, in future, more recent. In any case, pls edit and add the error message in case it also occurs with v0.5.

Comment: I have edited my question.